# Mass conservation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to prove that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \rho(x, t)g(x, t)dx = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \rho(x, t)\frac{D}{Dt}g(x, t)dx$$

I have tried to evaluate the integral using Liebniz' rule, so that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \rho(x, t)g(x, t)dx = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\left[\rho(x, t)g(x, t)\right]_t \,dx$$

but am unsure if the rule can be applied in this manner. Would I then apply some manner of multivariate product rule?

Any help much appreciated,

Will

Comment: Are $\rho$ and $g$ obeying any other relation? (like $\rho_t = ?$)

Answer (score 1):

This is reynolds transport theorem. You are missing alot of assumptions here.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the chain rule to the fundamental theorem of calculus.  You get $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \rho(x, t)g(x, t)dx = \frac {db(t)}{dt}\rho(x, t)g(x, t)-\frac {da(t)}{dt}\rho(x, t)g(x, t)$$  Maybe that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to plug in $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ into the functions $\rho$ and $g$ when you apply this method?

Comment: No. I suspect that is the point of the problem.  As $t$ increases by $dt$, $a(t)$  increases by $a'(t)dt$ so the integral decreases by ....

Comment: I'm not sure it will help regardless - the textbook I'm using suggests evaluating the LHS using Liebniz's formula, and that minus sign would get in the way, would it not?

Comment: The minus sign is not a problem.  You missed the point of my last comment.  As a(t) increases, the integral decreases, which is where the minus sign comes from.  I think your statement is false without some conditions on $\rho(x,t)$.  Let $g(x,t)=1$.  The derivative is zero, so the right side is zero.  Then if $\rho(x,t)=1$ and $b(t)$ increases faster than $a(t)$...  **Think**